# Child Parent Relationship and Inheritance in C

Tags: c, fork

I am totally new with C.

1. What are the process items that are inherited in a child created using `fork();`?
2. What are the process items that are different from the process's parent?

Comment: What? Please restate this question; it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Adam Robinson, It does make sense, but it is terribly worded.  @John is asking, what are the contents of [`man 2 fork`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html).

Comment: @rlibby: My comments preceded the edit.

Answer (score 15):

This hasn't got much to do with C, rather with `fork()`, which is a POSIX system call (and I guess it could behave differently on different systems).

I'd suggest you to read the [`fork` manual](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), which is really clear about this:

> `fork()` creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. The
>   new referred to as the child, is an exact duplicate of the calling
>   process, referred to as the parent, except for the following points:
>
> - The child has its own unique process ID, and this PID does not match the ID of any existing process group (`setpgid`(2)).
> - The child's parent process ID is the same as the parent's process ID.
> - The child does not inherit its parent's memory locks (`mlock`(2), `mlockall`(2)).
> - Process resource utilizations (`getrusage`(2)) and CPU time counters (`times`(2)) are reset to zero in the child.
> - The child's set of pending signals is initially empty (`sigpending`(2)).
> - The child does not inherit semaphore adjustments from its parent (`semop`(2)).
> - The child does not inherit record locks from its parent (`fcntl`(2)).
> - The child does not inherit timers from its parent (`setitimer`(2), `alarm`(2), `timer_create`(2)).
> - The child does not inherit outstanding asynchronous I/O operations from its parent (`aio_read`(3), `aio_write`(3)), nor does it inherit
>     any asynchronous I/O contexts from its parent (see `io_setup`(2)).
>
> The process attributes in the preceding list are all specified in
>   POSIX.1-2001.  The parent and child also differ with respect to the
>   following Linux-specific process attributes:
>
> - The child does not inherit directory change notifications (dnotify) from its parent (see the description of F_NOTIFY in `fcntl`(2)).
> - The `prctl`(2) `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` setting is reset so that the child does not receive a signal when its parent terminates.
> - Memory mappings that have been marked with the `madvise`(2) `MADV_DONTFORK` flag are not inherited across a `fork()`.
> - The termination signal of the child is always `SIGCHLD` (see `clone`(2)).
>
> Note the following further points:
>
> - The child process is created with a single thread -- the one that called `fork()`.  The entire virtual address space of the parent is
>     replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes, condition
>     variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of `pthread_atfork`(3)
>     may be helpful for dealing with problems that this can cause.
> - The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open file descriptors. Each file descriptor in the child refers to the same open
>     file description (see `open`(2)) as the corresponding file descriptor
>     in the parent.  This means that the two descriptors share open file
>     status flags, current file offset, and signal-driven I/O attributes
>     (see the description of `F_SETOWN` and `F_SETSIG` in `fcntl`(2)).
> - The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open message queue descriptors (see `mq_overview`(7)).  Each descriptor in the child
>     refers to the same open message queue description as the corresponding
>     descriptor in the parent.  This means that the two descriptors share
>     the same flags (`mq_flags`).
> - The child inherits copies of the parent's set of open directory streams (see `opendir`(3)).  POSIX.1-2001 says that the corresponding
>     directory streams in the parent and child may share the directory
>     stream positioning; on Linux/glibc they do not.

If you're interested about Linux, you should also check the `clone` system call, that lets you specify with more accuracy what you want.

Comment: That's not the POSIX `fork` manual. The POSIX manual is available at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html

Comment: by semaphore adjustments you mean if I have a fork within a locked region the child does not still belong in that locked region right? The child does inherit the semaphore though if it was created before fork

Answer (score 5):

The fork(2) man page on your system (`man fork`) should give you better details but generally the child only inherits the parent's list of file descriptors, including open files, sockets, and process handles.

From my system's man page (Mac OS X 10.6.6):

> The child process has its own copy of the parent's descriptors.
>       These descriptors reference the same underlying objects, so
>       that, for instance, file pointers in file objects are shared
>       between the child and the parent, so that an lseek(2) on a
>       descriptor in the child process can affect a subsequent read or
>       write by the parent.  This descriptor copying is also used by
>       the shell to establish standard input and output for newly cre-
>       ated processes as well as to set up pipes.

Answer (score 2):

See the [official description of fork(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no object-oriented inheritence in C.

Fork'ing in C is basically the process being stopped while it is running, and an entire copy of it being made in (effectively) a different memory space, then both processes being told to continue.  They will both continue from where the parent was paused.  The only way you can tell which process you are in is to check the return value of the `fork()` call.

In such a situation the child doesn't really inherit everything from the parent process, it's more like it gets a complete copy of everything the parent had.

Comment: if we would not use exec() family of system calls then parent process would not be able to resume.And if only execute fork() inside the parent then whole of the system data segment (PCB) would be copied except PID AND PPID.

Comment: That's not true.  You can fork without an exec().  You just can't get the fork()'d process to run any code other than the parent process code.  exec() overlays the process with "some other code", resets the registers and alters the instruction pointer to start at the "newly copied into the process" code.  Exec() is not necessary to "continue processing" in either the parent or the child.

Comment: yes you are true but what is the use of creating a child process which does not have its own code and data segment.because in fork we do not specify the program which is to be converted into a process it doesn't make any sense only to have fork() system call.Can you give example when it would be beneficial only to use fork but not exec()family of system calls.

Comment: There are many programs that can benefit from forking without exec overlay.  Basically all of the divide and conquer solutions need the same "client code" with the parent code being the point of coordination.  OSCAR (the clustering suite) would gladly move the children processes to free compute nodes, so only a simple fork would be needed.  Also, why would you exec over a bunch of programs running in coordination to handle the same issue (perhaps for redundancy) anyway?

Comment: @Algorithmist I know this is old, but examples of fork() and no exec() - apache web server, which has a single parent, and multiple children which service requests. Also sshd uses fork() without exec to help on security. Just because you have the same code doesn't mean you do the same code path.

Answer (score 0):

The only things of child that are different its parent are its

*PPID i.e parent process id* and

*PID process id*.

And when it comes to similarity child process inherits its parent's FILE DESCRIPTOR table thus you would see that always three FILE DESCRIPTORS of child are always occupied which correspond to **STDIN,STDOUT and STDERR**.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The child process is dissimilar to its parent in other ways, for example timers are not copied. See the POSIX specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html